# Show that if $\langle u,v\rangle_1=0\implies\langle u,v\rangle_2=0$ then $\langle{\cdot},{\cdot}\rangle_1=c\langle{\cdot},{\cdot}\rangle_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let a vector space with two inner product defined. If for every $u,v\in V$ s.t. $\langle u,v\rangle_1=0$ then $\langle u,v\rangle_2=0$ show that $\langle{\cdot},{\cdot}\rangle_1=c\langle{\cdot},{\cdot}\rangle_2$ for some $c>0$.

This is the exercise 11 on page 191 of *Linear algebra done right, third edition* of Axler. I had proven the statement for finite dimensional $V$ using and orthonormal basis for $(V,\langle{\cdot},{\cdot}\rangle_1)$.

However the existence of an orthonormal basis is not ensured for infinite dimensional vector spaces. My question: I must assume that the dimension of $V$ is finite for this exercise, or there is a way to prove the statement?

EDIT: I found the same exercise [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251945/suppose-langle-cdot-cdot-rangle-1-and-langle-cdot-cdot-rangle-2-are-inne?rq=1), but the answer is not understandable to me, when it says that if it is true for any subspace $V'$ of $V$ it remains true for $V$, why?

Comment: The proposed link does not assume $V$ is finite dimensional

Comment: @Jorge, you are right. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you can show that for any $V'$ there is a constant $c$ with $\langle u,v \rangle_1=c\langle u,v\rangle_2$.

First prove that the $c$ is the same for every $V'$.

Pick $V'$ and $V''$, if we consider $V^{'} + V^{''}$ we get that the constants of $V'$ and $V^{''}$ are both equal to the constant of $V^{'}+V^{''}$.

Finally, pick $u$ and $v$ in $V$. We wish to prove that $\langle u,v \rangle_1=c\langle u,v\rangle_2$. Easy, consider $V^{'}=span\{u,v\}$ and enjoy!